# Importing images from Oscommerce to Magento

Tags: magento, batch-file, data-migration

I'm in the process of migrating to Magento. I'm at a step where I need to move images from oscommerce to Magento.  I've seen that Magento places product images in media/catalog/product.  I can also see how when an image is added to this folder, it takes the first character of the file name uploaded as a folder and the second character of the file extension.

So the structure will look like this media/catalog/product/a/b/abc.jpg

Is there a script which can create this automatically as I have just over 3000 image products to import?

It would need to take the 1st and 2nd characters of the file name and create folders from these characters.  Then it would dump the file in the last folder, that being the second character.

Cheers,

Jonah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through all the files in the folder that the images are in (just tweak the dir to the full path) and will create a folder for each (in the `media\catalog\product` dir - again, tweak to full path) based on the first letter of the file.

It will then create a subfolder under the first letter named by the second letter of the file.

All files matching the first 2 letters are moved into the subfolder (again, tweak the `media\catalog\product` part of the path to be a full path).

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\media\catalog\product
for %%a in (C:\imagefolder\*.*) do (
set char=%%~nxa
set char1=!char:~0,1!
set char2=!char:~1,1!
if not exist !char1! md !char1!
if not exist !char1!\!char2! md !char1!\!char2!
move "%%a" !char1!\!char2!
)
```

Comment: @downvoter? The least you could do is explain why you have downvoted!

Comment: I tried your script but it didn't work unfortunately. When I ran it, it created folders from the file names but it didn't put the file in the last folder.  Also, if there are two files and they both begin with the same two characters, the script should create the folders from the first and second character then dump the file in the second folder.  When the script reads the second file, it should notice these characters have already been created.  The script will then move the file in the directory in where the first and second character of its name has already been created.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do filenames with the same 2 starting letters, and added some more info.

Comment: I have just tested my latest edit and it works perfectly. I had a file `C:\a\New Text Document.txt` and a `.rar` (same name) and it moved them into `C:\a\N\e`.

Comment: I tried your script again and changed the dir, but I'm getting a message saying 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect'.  I'm running this bat file within the directory where the images are.

Comment: I was getting that error as well, but my latest edit fixes that, make sure you have `char=%%~nxa` instead of `char=%%a`.